# Identificar las fecha consecutivas coincidentes en un varios data frame

Tags: r, rstudio

Hola a todos podría ayudarme con un problema que tengo:
Tengo 13 data frame de estaciones climáticas con 5 variables “Fecha, precipitación, evapotranspiración, temperatura máxima y Temperatura mínima”, con distintas longitudes, lo primero que hice fue homogenizar las bases de datos a una fecha de inicio y una fecha final, para así identificar las fechas diarias faltantes, mediante este código:

```
ee_20017 <- group_by(ee_20017 []) %>%
  complete(FECHA = seq(min(FECHA), max(FECHA), by = "1 day"),
           fill = list("na"));
```

Al tener todas las bases de datos homegizadas, las concatene con el comando cbind:

```
esta <- cbind(e_20017, e_20027,e_20039,e_20117,e_20134,e_20277,e_20289,e_20325,
              e_20330, e_30081,e_30090,e_30147,e_30224);
```

El propósito de unirlas es para identificar poder identificar de mis 13 data frame a o en cual fecha coinciden en datos, digamos que por ejemplo e_20017 y e_20027, coinciden en los mismos no se 5 años de datos consecutivos y así compararlos ya se e manera individual con las demás data frame o con el mismo data frame.

Intente la función unión y me dice los datos que coincidentes con cada variable de cada data frame:

```
ee_20039_20017 <-union(ee_20017, ee_20039)
```

Mi duda es sabes si hay una función en que haga esto en un solo data frame como el que yo concatene para así que me devuelva un data frame con los datos que coinciden con fecha y con observaciones, la función de union() creo que sirve pero lo tengo que aplicar muchas veces si alguien tiene una función que automatice eso o si no hay solución pues aplicarme para crear una función que haga lo que pregunto ahora.

Saludos y espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Bienvenido Jorge a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿No me termina de quedar claro que es lo que buscas finalmente? ¿Consolidar los datos de todas las estaciones por fecha, en una sola fila? ¿Ver que fechas tienen las mismas observaciones en distintas estaciones?

Comment: Si me gustaría identificar que estaciones tienen datos consecutivos en la mis fecha, por ejemplo la estación e_20017 comparándolas con el resto de las estaciones tiene datos consecutivos desde el 1 enero del 2000 al 15 de marzo del 2010 y eso tenerlo en una tabla, disculpen si no me doy a explicar bien es mi primera pregunta en este foro